# How to add custom list item in action bar searchview

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I've added a searchView to the toolbar, and added the search suggestions. The problem is I want to add a custom list-item to the search suggestions as the last item to clear the suggestions(search history). How can I do this or is there a better way to show user a "clear history " option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the Adding Recent Queries Developer Guide, given [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html), you will see that there is a section where it has been shown how to clear the recent queries saved, which is what you want when you say clear the history(previous searches.)

I am copying the code from the Developer guide just for reference. ( Please check the guide for complete usage and how to implement it in your code. )

```
SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
        HelloSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, HelloSuggestionProvider.MODE);
suggestions.clearHistory();
```